# Just some quick questions on using string

Tags: java, string

We have to make a program on printing initials, which seems pretty easy ok, but I don't know how to cut the string when the input is all on one line using the scanner class in.nextline();. I cant seem to find a way to cut the string using only string methods. Also, another problem arose when I have to also be able to adjust if there isn't a middle name either. if anyone can help me or lead me in the right direction that would be nice.

Comment: Seems like your question is Java related, not Javascript related. You should also post your code so people can help debug it.

Comment: idk how to enter in the code in right format

Answer (score 1):

If you can use split function as you can see below:

```
String inputString=s.nextLine(); 
String [] str = inputString.split(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want to have extract only first letter then - 
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestStringInput {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Please Enter the Name");
   String input = scan.nextLine();
   int value = input.indexOf(" ",input.indexOf(" "));
   String result = input.substring(0,value);
   System.out.println(result);
   }
}
```

But if you want to Extract Starting 2 Initials then change this line-
int value = input.indexOf(" ",input.indexOf(" ")+1);

Answer (score -1):

As Stephen mentioned, your question is about Java, consider re-tagging.

You can use a for loop to iterate through the string. Remember a string is an object. It would help a lot if you posted your code.

Comment: Sorry about the post, I tried to make my title as clear as possible

Comment: No worries, could you take a screenshot of your code so we can see please

Comment: How do enter in  my code without messing up the format

Comment: Check out this thread mate:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Im new to computers, even though im a programmer ik, how would I be able to send my screenshot of my code to this site

Comment: @disrudecoder this should have been a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I realize how dumb I sound and I tried to post my code in a comment. I'm really bad at this but il'll learn

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HW03 {
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = "";

        System.out.println("What are your first, middle and last names?");
        str = in.nextLine();


    }

}
```